# VBA Filter Function - Prevent Error On Click

Tags: vba, filter, autofilter

hopefully this is an easy fix, but I'm still too new to this to know what to look for in the functions. I'm basically making an autofilter function for a work in progress, and everything works fine, unless I start off clicking the "clear filter" function block I made.

I wanted to include this function so I can click on "Filter 1", "Filter 2" and then a quick "Clear Filter" to bring things back to normal. If I didn't click "Filter 1" or "Filter 2" before clicking "Clear Filter", it goes into debug mode. Is there a way around that?

```
Sub Filter1()
  Dim LastRow As Long

  LastRow = Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  Range("A1:H" & LastRow).Select
  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="VariableX"

End Sub

Sub Clear()

  Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance on any help with this!

Comment: Is this code in a worksheet's private code sheet or a public module code sheet?

Comment: It is in the public I believe. I can't say I'm 100% sure, as I haven't delved very far into that stuff yet, but I don't think I have any private stuff on my vba yet. I literally just have a huge list of Sub Commands. Basically what I have displayed is exactly what I have in my actual code, just more Filters and such.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get error after "Filter 1" or "Filter 2" is because the module selects a range.

> Sub Clear()
>
> 'Must select before working with selection
>
> Range("A1").Select
>
> **Selection**.AutoFilter
>
> End Sub